Tikz: access a color defined in hex format out of list?
I know how to define a color in hex format and use it in tikz:
\definecolor{myColor}{HTML}{CAFDE3};
...
\draw[fill=myColor,thick]...

But I need to pick the color out of a list. So I start with this code:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \def\colorlist{{FF5733},{33FF57},{3357FF},{FF33A8},{33FFF5}}
    \pgfmathparse{\colorlist[2]}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Unfortunatelly, this first code gives the error:

%Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `FF5733'...

Second try: I enclose the color definition in the list as strings:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \def\colorlist{{"FF5733"},{"33FF57"},{"3357FF"},{"FF33A8"},{"33FFF5"}}
    \pgfmathparse{\colorlist[2]}
    \let\mycolor=\pgfmathresult
    \definecolor{ringColor}{HTML}{\mycolor};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

But this now gives the error:

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.

Any idea on how to store some colors in hex format in a list and retrieve it later to use it in Tikz?
BTW, Copilot gives this, but it doesn't work either...
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \def\colorlist{{"FF5733"},{"33FF57"},{"3357FF"},{"FF33A8"},{"33FFF5"}}
    \pgfmathparse{\colorlist[2]}
    \edef\mycolor{\pgfmathresult}
    \expandafter\definecolor\expandafter{ringColor}{HTML}{\mycolor}

    \draw[fill=ringColor,thick] (0,0) circle (1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Same error:

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.


You can use \clist_item:Nn provided by L3 for this. The following defines two user-land macros to first set a new colorlist, and then access items from a defined colorlist.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\setcolorlist{mm}
  { \josephmarie_set_colorlist:nn {#1} {#2} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \josephmarie_set_colorlist:nn #1
  {
    \clist_clear_new:c { l__josephmarie_colorlist_#1_clist }
    \clist_set:cn { l__josephmarie_colorlist_#1_clist }
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\usecolor{mm}
  { \josephmarie_use_color:nn {#1} {#2} }
\cs_new:Npn \josephmarie_use_color:nn #1#2
  {
    \clist_if_exist:cTF { l__josephmarie_colorlist_#1_clist }
      { \clist_item:cn { l__josephmarie_colorlist_#1_clist } {#2} }
      { \msg_expandable_error:nnn { josephmarie } { unknown-colorlist } {#1} }
  }
\msg_new:nnn { josephmarie } { unknown-colorlist } { Unknown~ colorlist~ #1 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setcolorlist{test}{FF5733,33FF57,3357FF,FF33A8,33FFF5}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \definecolor{ringColor}{HTML}{\usecolor{test}{2}}
  \draw[fill=ringColor,thick] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



What should we change to be able to use a color index like here: \tikzmath{
\myColorIndex = 2+1;
}
\definecolor{ringColor}{HTML}{\usecolor{test}{\myColorIndex}}

@JosephMarie \usecolor{test}{2+1} works.

The second argument understands simple arithmetic (+, -, *, /, and parenthesis, nothing too fancy, and / always rounds to the nearest integer, so is no integer division).

@JosephMarie if you want to use pgfmath you have to make sure that your output doesn't contain a ., so use int(...) around your expression, so \tikzmath{ \myColorIndex = int(2+1); }.

It works! Thank you so much!
